# How do I detect if adblock is preventing "Signin with Facebook" in nopcommerce?

Tags: facebook, nopcommerce, adblock

I'm using the `Signin with Facebook` plugin with `Nopcommerce` here:

- http://favalife.azurewebsites.net/login

I noticed that in Chrome, the facebook button doesn't appear if Adblock is running.

What can I do to make the front-end look "better" or be more functional and allow for Facebook logins while Adblock is hiding the image, and/or the following code:

```
<a href="/Plugins/ExternalAuthFacebook/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fcart" class="facebook-btn">
    &nbsp;</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add apporpriate styles to \Plugins\ExternalAuth.Facebook\Content\facebookstyles.css file

Comment: I see, the block is from `https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/fanboy-annoyance.txt` and matches the class: `facebook-btn` renaming the style should fix it.